# More information on working with plug ins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, devextreme

Okay, So I am following the instructions listed at 
https://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/KA18796

However, I just don't quite understand it.  On step 3

> Save config.xml in your archive and use PhoneGap Build for building a
>   native package. The full list of plugins can be found here.

So this is how I compile my application into a finished product, So am I not able to develop in visual studio and test out the application using Courier? Or do I have to have the product completed when I do this?

I'm trying to implement a barcode scanner using

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo

But I just don't see how I'm supposed to test the barcode?

Comment: The steps you are following are very old (phonegap 2.9 as we are now in 4.0) and it talks about building using the online service "Phonegap Build", not build locally as you seem to be trying to. I sugest you read Cordova docs instead.

Answer (score 0):

You referred to old version docs.

Check this out. http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

There are **two** options to build an app

- Online PhoneGap Build tool ( phonegap.com )
- Command line

The line you highlighted above was talking about the online build tool. In which general steps are like this:

- Write your code ( html, css, js and related images as well)
- Configure config.xml for information like what plugins to use, preferences, platforms, version and some other settings
- just archive the folder and deploy using online build tool
- Directly download on device for respective platform

The command line tool is very simple to use. Just follow the link I shared above and it will help.

Its possible to work in MS VS and use Command line in order to automate develop, test and build.

To use Bar code:

- First understand how CL works
- create a project
- Add bar code plugin
- deploy on device
- generate a sample bar code using any site like www.barcode-generator.org
- Scan it and see the results

Answer (score 0):

Keep your plugins in config.xml.

Now, just build application template by right-clicking the project.
this will build your template by posting it to phonegap build server.

Hence, you can test your application on your device.